# jQuery Get Ellipse Text

Tags: jquery, ellipse

Now that firefox finally supports ellipse text I'm looking for a way to determine if ellipse is actually happening on an element.

My thought is to check the text to see if ... is present(not great but will work).  However I haven't found a way to return the ellipse text and not the actual text.

You can see the here concept: http://jsfiddle.net/UaSYd/

What I want jQuery to return is what is actually displayed IE: This ...

Ideas?

Comment: I am using a slickgrid with columns that the width can be set by the user on the fly.  I have it so the text becomes ellipsed if the column width is shorter than the text.  If this happens I want to add a tooltip to that column cell.

Answer (score 6):

What I do to determine whether a cell has an ellipsis or not is to compare the cells scrollWidth with the clientWidth. This seems to work. If you still need it of course ;)

```
jTable.find("td").each(function () {
    if (this.scrollWidth > this.clientWidth) {
        this.title = this.innerText;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've browsed and found a million answers to this question but this one is the only one that works and is efficient Thumbs Up man